# Некорректно считывается индекс из справочника (ComboBox) при записи в таблицу БД. Python+PyQT5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Прошу помощи, коллеги. Пишу программку на Python, PyQT5 и БД MSSQL.
Описание проблемы: в графическом интерфейсе создана карточка для добавления записи в таблицу Базы данных. В данной карточке есть объект ComboBox для выбора значений из справочника (другой таблицы связанной с помощью внешнего ключа). Проблема в том, что при записи в таблицу(карточки) индекс из комбобокса не меняется, не смотря на различные выборки из этого комбобокса( по дефолту записывается значение 1). Поле id_block является связкой по внешнему ключу на таблицу со справочными значениями. Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой довольно тривиальной задачей, но я пока так  и не смог решить данный вопрос. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

```
 def adddata(self):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-49J58F3\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Plan;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
    query = "insert into dbo.Card_plan (nn,name,metering,volume,date_end,responsible,txt_name, id_block) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    nn = self.lineEdit_2.text()
    name = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
    metering = self.lineEdit_6.text()
    volume = self.lineEdit_3.text()
    date_end = self.dateEdit.text()
    responsible = self.lineEdit_4.text()
    txt_name = self.lineEdit_5.text()
    id_block = self.comboBox.currentIndex()
    if nn.strip(" ")!="" and name.strip(" ")!="" and metering.strip(" ")!="" and volume.strip(" ")!="" and date_end.strip(" ")!="" and responsible.strip(" ")!="" and txt_name.strip(" ")!="":
        value = (nn, name, metering, volume, date_end, responsible, txt_name, id_block)
        conn.execute(query, value)
        conn.commit()
        self.upd()
```

Comment: если смотреть в отладчике, в id_block то правильно индекс получается? может у вас комбобоксов там куча

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev комбобокс один. Выводит значение 0 и 1 (Пока в справочнике 2 значения). Но на деле в базе id у них значения 1 и 2 соответственно. Думаю, может я не правильно таблицы связал все-таки между собой.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.